# how make a filter or autocomplete in a field in django from html page

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am a newbie in [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), I make a Django form and show this in a `HTML`. in this form I have a `field products`, when a user selects a product, it shows all products.

Is there a way to implement a filter to search among all the products when the user writes the product name in the field?

Comment: it would be more helpful if your code was visible.

Answer (score 0):

The way to filter a `list of Strings` in `Python` that contains a specific substring, would be like this:

```
filtered_products = filter(lambda item: 'productName' in item , products)
```

Is this helpful? Notice that 'productName' string should be the variable that takes the string of your field.